# Focus textfield

Tags: android

I have several "TextInputEditText" with some which have this behavior

```
etField.setOnClickListener(this);
etField.setFocusable(false);
```

If the user click on the edit text, according to the case, i show a "DatePickerDialog" or "AlertDialog" with choice items.

I have a problem with the keyboard.
The user  enter the information in the first normal edit text, if the user tap on next, the next texts (with previous behaviors)  are skipped until the next normal text.

how to give focus and show the alertDialog or DatePickerDialog same if I have no focusable?

**PART OF MY CODE**

```
if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(TypeField.DATE)) {
            etField.setOnClickListener(this);
            etField.setFocusable(false);
            etField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME);
            etField.setText(value);



        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(TypeField.CHAINE)) {
            etField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            etField.setText(value);
            if (nom != null && nom.size() > 0)
            {

                etField.setFocusable(false);
                etField.setOnClickListener(this);




            }

        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(TypeField.ENTIER)) {
            etField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
            etField.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
            etField.setText(value);

        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(TypeField.REEL)) {

            etField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

```
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(TypeField.DATE)){
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), this, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


            dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                }
            });

            dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Annuler", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {

                    }
                }
            });
            dialog.show();

        }
        else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(TypeField.CHAINE)){
            String valueSelected = this.getValue();

            String[] labels = [...]

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(labels, iChecked, new ItemSelectionChanged());

            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

            alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

                }
            });

            String titleChoice = fieldDescription.getLabel();
            alertDialog.setTitle(titleChoice);
            //alertDialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"OK", new ItemActionChanged());
            //alertDialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"ANNULER", new ItemActionChanged());
            //alertDialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL,"EFFACER", new ItemActionChanged());
            alertDialog.show();
        }
}
```

Comment: Provide some code how are you validating the focus change ?

Answer (score 0):

using text watcher we can achieve.

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


//DatePickerDialog  code comes here


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
In XML, I do this.

```
            <EditText
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:id="@+id/edt_treeCondition"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

To my root tag, I make it focusable true because the layout needs a focus.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Now, use the click listener successfully.

```
edt_treeCondition.setOnClickListener{
//Do whatever you want
}
```

I actually don't understand the question thoroughly but hope this helps your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

if it can serve someone, the solution for me has been:

```
etField.setOnClickListener(this);
//etField.setFocusable(false);
//etField.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
etField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME);
etField.setText(value);

etField.setFocusable(true);
etField.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
etField.setTextIsSelectable(false);
etField.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
activeFocus(etField,tilField);

 private void activeFocus(EditText etField, TextInputLayout tilField) {

        etField.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
        etField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                GILogUtil.i(TAG, "focus");
                if (hasFocus == true){
                    onClick(etField);
                }
            }
        });


    }
```